# Trader on a frozen world during social upheaval

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Please help me identify this book

I remember very little about the plot of this book, however, I remember the beginning pretty vividly.

The perspective moves between one or more humans and the natives of the planet.  The world is a very cold world.  In my mind's eye it's a frozen place like one of the Galilean moons or Titan.

Humans must wear special suits (I don't recall whether these are full up space suits or thermal suits with respirators) to protect themselves.  The protagonist is a very rich trader on a trade mission and is pretty arrogant and hard to like.

The aliens partially see in the infrared, so humans appear to glow "hotly".  My impression is that the aliens are bipedal and possibly have jackal or hyena shaped heads (but I could be mistaken about this).  The natives are pissed at the humans for some reason and attack and decimate the human trade delegation and ship crew.

The human protagonist survives.

My impression is that he had to trek cross country for safety but I really don't recall any more of the story.  I think the natives were hunting him.

Comment: Dang, this *almost* sounded like Ursula le Guin's *Left Hand of Darkness*. But then no. You should read *Left Hand of Darkness* though. :)

Comment: This could *possibly* be it.  I read it long ago and I might be mixing two stories.  You are right though, now I'll have to read (or reread :) ) *Left Hand of Darkness*.

Comment: This could be Alan Dean Foster's IceRigger series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be the middle story (*[Territory](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/141655520X/141655520X___3.htm)*) from *Trader to the Stars* by Poul Anderson.

The protagonist ([Nicholas van Rijn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_van_Rijn)) fits the description of rich, arrogant, and hard to like.

The story involves a trade mission attacked by natives. There was some ecological angle to the planet (it may have been frozen). I can't remember details of the natives.  Unfortunately I can't find my copy at the moment (it may be in a box in the loft).

Comment: I thumbed through this, and it is indeed set on a cold planet.  But I didn't see any viewpoint switches to the aliens.

Comment: I'm digging around for a link to a summary of the story but haven't found one yet.  This seems right because my mental image of the trader fits nicely with the persona of Nicholas van Rijn but I just can't say yet.

Comment: @Jim2B - I may have got the correct character but the wrong story. There are a few Nicholas van Rijn stories. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_van_Rijn)

Comment: @Fruitbat:
Is there any particular reason you removed the link to a legit electronic copy of the story you're citing? :)

Comment: @Sean Duggan - The link was to a review of "David Falkyn: Star Trader". I couldn't find "Trader to the Stars" on that website.

Comment: @Fruitbat:
Ah. I linked to "Territory". If you click through to the contents at http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/141655520X/141655520X_toc.htm, you can see which items are in the anthology.

Comment: Here's my real-time summary as I thumb through it again: Story starts with a native attack on the trading station. Van R and a girl who doesn't like him flee into the cold wastes because the rest of the traders flee in the spacecraft.  They have a native ally (native clans are warring).  They use a Terran vehicle as shelter.  VR complains because there is no liquor.  VR works a swindle to save them, get a trade deal, and may end up with the girl. (The last 2 sentences could apply to any VR story...)

Comment: @Sean Duggan - I see. I've replaced the link (now goes straight to text of story hopefully).